# When running Azure Data Factory Activities in Azure Batch, how should asynchronicity be handled

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

**Background**

I have somewhat simplified this scenario but this is the general problem.

I am using an Azure Data Factory to ingest data from a custom API into a table in Azure Data Warehouse. I am using an IDotNetActivity to run the C# code that calls the API and loads the data into the data warehouse. The activity runs in Azure Batch.

Within the activity itself, before I call the custom API, I load a list of people from a file in Azure Blob storage.
I then make a call to the custom API for each person in the file.
These calls are made sequentially one after another.
The problem is that this approach takes too long.
The file size is likely to grow so the time it takes will only get worse.

**Things I've tried to improve performance**

- Making the API calls asynchronous and calling them in batches of 3. Strangely this ran slower. It looks like the batch process does not handle async / await all that well.
- Other strangeness we have seen is that MoreLinq's Batch command didn't work at all. I have checked the source code for this:
  https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs . This uses yield return but I have no idea why this isn't working or even if it is related to the async / await problem.

**The Main Question**

Does Azure Batch support async / await?

**Further questions**

- If Azure doesn't support async / await then what is a better way to approach this problem? i.e. Using a job manager and spinning up more nodes.
- Can anyone shed some light as to why MoreLinq's Batch doesn't work in Azure Batch?
  Here is a snippet of the affected code:

  ```
  List<int> personIds = GetPersonIds(clientAddress, clientUsername, clientPassword);
  var customResults = new List<CustomApiResult>();
  foreach (var personIdsBatch in personIds.Batch(100))
  {
      customResults.AddRange(GetCustomResultsByBatch(address, username, password, personIdsBatch));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, `personIds.Batch(100)` just batches `personIds` into sized (100) buckets.

```html
//method1
foreach (var personIdsBatch in personIds.Batch(100))
{
    customResults.AddRange(GetCustomResultsByBatch(address, username, password, personIdsBatch));
}

//method2
customResults.AddRange(GetCustomResultsByBatch(address, username, password, personIds));
```

Both the above methods would make a call to your custom API for each person sequentially, while `method1` has added the additional logical for handling the same task.

> Does Azure Batch support async / await?

Base on your code, I defined the `IDotNetActivity` implemention as follows, you could refer to it:

```
public class MyDotNetActivity : IDotNetActivity
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices, IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        return ExecuteAsync(linkedServices, datasets, activity, logger).Result;
    }

    async Task<IDictionary<string, string>> ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices, IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        List<int> personIds = await GetPersonIds("{clientAddress}", "{clientUsername}", "{clientPassword}");
        var tasks = new List<Task<List<CustomApiResult>>>();
        foreach (var personIdsBatch in personIds.Batch(100))
        {
            tasks.AddRange(GetCustomResultsByBatch("{address}", "{username}", "{password}", "{personIdsBatch}"));
        }

        var taskResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        List<CustomApiResult> customResults = taskResults.SelectMany(r=>r).ToList();

        //process the custom api results

        return new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    async Task<List<CustomApiResult>> GetCustomResultsByBatch(string address, string username, string password, IEnumerable<int> personIdsBatch)
    {
        //Get Custom Results By Batch
        return new List<CustomApiResult>();
    }

    async Task<List<int>> GetPersonIds(string clientAddress, string clientUsername, string clientPassword)
    {
        //load a list of people from a file in Azure Blob storage
        return new List<int>(); 
    }
}
```

Also, I assumed that you could leverage [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows to execute your synchronistical jobs in parallel:

```
List<int> personIds = GetPersonIds(clientAddress, clientUsername, clientPassword);
var customResults = new List<CustomApiResult>();
Parallel.ForEach(personIds.Batch(100), 
new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism=5
},
(personIdsBatch) =>
{
    var results = GetCustomResultsByBatch(address, username, password, personIdsBatch);
    lock (customResults)
    {
        customResults.AddRange(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce, this works. MoreLinq Batch works. This wasn't working several months ago. Also the async / await code works fine. I don't know why it wasn't working before.